# Get associated parent keys in JS object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a Javascript object that looks like this:

```
[{
  "House 1": [
    "Room 1": [
      {"1": "TV"},
      {"2": "Sofa"},
    ],
    "Room 2": [
      {"3": "Desk"},
      {"4": "Sink"},
    ]
  ],
  "House 2": [
    "Room 1": [
      {"5": "Chair"},
      {"6": "Iron"},
    ],
    "Room 1": [
      {"7": "Safe"},
      {"8": "Cupboard"},
    ]
  ],
}]
```

I would like to pass an item key like `4` (Sink item), and be able to retrieve the Room Index (Room 2) and the House Key (House 1).

I would I be able to achieve this? I understand the `.find()` might be be the trick, but where this is multi-dimensional I can't wrap my head around how to do this.

Edit:

I can loop through all the objects like this, but I'm wondering if theres an easier way.

```
// loop through houses
for (var key in obj) {

    // loop rooms
    for (var key2 in obj[key]) {

        // loop through assets
        for (var key3 in obj[key][key2]) {

            if(key3 == venueId) {
                console.log("found it!" + obj[key][key2][key3]);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The structure is invalid.

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut Do you think you could be more constructive and offer the OP something in the way of positive advice?

Comment: I think your structure looks like associative arrays in php, if I'm not mistaken. Anywho, you can't do this in javascript. Look at your arrays with keys again, and probably yo would want to make them objects.

Comment: You can nest loops (or loop-based [methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Iteration_methods)), loop by object [properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames). What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Imran could you switch in both values with key "House n" square brackets to curly brackets (or add curly brackets into it but this will add extra depth)?

Comment: @barbsan updated my question with what I've tried so far, not the most efficient way for sure.

Comment: @Imran what they meant is that this structure is invalid JS: `[ "Room 1": [ /* ... */ ] ]`. If you just paste your example (input data) in a browsers console, you'll get a SyntaxError.

Comment: [
    "Room 1": [
      {"1": "TV"},
      {"2": "Sofa"},
    ]  how could javascript array like this. You didn't mention exact input. Please write exact input

Answer (score 0):

What about [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
var a ={
  "House 1": {
    "Room 1": [
      {"1": "TV"},
      {"2": "Sofa"},
    ],
    "Room 2": [
      {"3": "Desk"},
      {"4": "Sink"},
    ]
  },
  "House 2": {
    "Room 1": [
      {"5": "Chair"},
      {"6": "Iron"},
    ],
    "Room 2": [
      {"7": "Safe"},
      {"8": "Cupboard"},
    ]
  }
};
var search=4;
Object.keys(a).reduce((ans,houseIn)=>{

     return ans||Object.keys(a[houseIn]).reduce((ans,roomIn)=>{
     
           return ans|| a[houseIn][roomIn].reduce((ans,item,itemIn)=>{
             if(parseInt(Object.keys(item)[0])==search){   
                console.log("found it! " + a[houseIn][roomIn][itemIn][Object.keys(item)[0]]);
                return true;
               }else{
               return false;
               }
             
          },false);


   },false);
    
  
},false);
```